# can you do a jquery mobile popup on ajax response event?

Tags: ajax, forms, jquery-mobile, popup

Was hoping to use the popup and I am pretty sure I am trying to use it incorrectly.  Any ideas on how this should work?  Can you use the popup in this manner?

```
<script>

function onSuccess(data, status)
{
    data = $.trim(data);
    $("#notification").text(data);
}

function onError(data, status)
{
    data = $.trim(data);
    //$("#notification").text(data);
    $("#notification").popup(data);        }        

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").click(function(){

        var formData = $("#callAjaxForm").serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendmsg.php",
            cache: false,
            data: formData,
            success: onSuccess,
            error: onError
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to use the JQM [popup widget](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/index.html), first your missing the closing `}` from your `onError function`. Second to use the popup widget you can first set the data

`$("#myPopupContent").text(data)`

Then to display you use the [open](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/popup/methods.html) method

`$("#myPopup").popup("open")`

Comment: i guess what is not clear to me is the way you create an instance of this.  Using your example, I assumed it would be something like this... `<div class="responseNotice" id="notification" data-role="popup"></div>`

Comment: That should be the correct markup for the popup widget, but are you sure you are using the right version of JQM? The popup widget is not yet included in the stable release (1.1.1 as of this point). You might want to replace the text of a child element inside the popup container instead of the parent div (eg `<div id="myPopup" data-role="popup"> <div id="popupContent"></div></div>` since JQM modifies the markup after it initializes the widget.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the release.  The popup widget page I was looking at didn't mention that it was not part of the stable release yet.  Oh well.